# Get value from a column with regex

Tags: regex, backtracking, capture-group

I have lines of text similar to this:

`value1|value2|value3 etc.`

The values itself are not interesting. The type of delimeter is also unimportant, just like the number of fields. There could be 100 column, there could be only 5.

I would like to know what is the usual way to write a regexp which will put any given column's value into a capture group.

For example if I would like to get the content of the third field:

`[^\|]+?\|[^\|]+?\|(?<capture_group>[^\|]+?)\|`

Maybe a little bit nicer version:

`(?:[^\|]+?\|){2}(?<capture_group>[^\|]+?)\|`

But this could be the 7th, the 100th, the 1000th, it doesn't matter.

My problem is, that after a while I run into catastrophic backtracking or simply extremely low running times.

What is the usual way to solve a problem like this?

**Edit:**

For further clarification: this is a use case where further string operations are simply not permitted. Workarounds are not possible. I would like to know if there's a way simply based on regex or not.

Comment: Split on delimiter and get the Nth value from resulted array. What language are you using?

Comment: To get any field you may use `^(?:[^|]*\|){n-1}([^|]*)`

Answer (score 1):

As you stated:

> My problem is, that after a while I run into catastrophic backtracking
> or simply extremely low running times.
>
> What is the usual way to solve a problem like this?

IMHO, You should prefer to perform string operations when you have a predefined structure in string (like for your case `|` character is used as a separator) because string operations are faster than using Regex which is *designed to find a pattern*. Like, in case the separators may change and we have to identify it first and then split based on separator, here the need of a Regex comes.

e.g.,

```
value1|value2;value3-value4
```

For your case, you can simply perform string split based on the separator character and access the respected index from an array.

**EDIT:**

If Regex is your only option then try using this regex:

```
^((.+?)\|){200}
```

Here `200` is the element I wish to access and seems a bit less time consuming than yours.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PamTiF/1)

Comment: The first Subpattern can be a non-capturing Group: ^(?:(.+?)\|){200}

Answer (score 0):

> For example if I would like to get the content of the third field:
>
> ```
> [^\|]+?\|[^\|]+?\|(?<capture_group>[^\|]+?)\|
> ```
>
> Maybe a little bit nicer version:
>
> ```
> (?:[^\|]+?\|){2}(?<capture_group>[^\|]+?)\|
> ```
>
> But this could be the 7th, the 100th, the 1000th, it doesn't matter.

As a matter of "steps", using capture groups will cost more step.

However, using capture groups will allow you to condense your pattern and use a curly bracketed quantifier.

In your first pattern above, you can get away with "greedy" negated character classes (remove the `?`) because they will halt at the next `|`, and you don't need to escape the pipe inside the square brackets.

When you want to access a "much later" positioned substring in the input string,  not using a quantifier is going to require a horrifically long pattern and make it very, very difficult to comprehend the exact point that will be matched.  In these cases, it would be pretty silly not to use a capture group and a quantifier.

I agree with Toto's comment; accessing an array of split results is going to be a very sensible solution if possible.